# SQL Server Split Day in 4 Blocks of 2 hours

Tags: sql, split

I have few records of tasks with StartTime and StopTime and I would like to split it in 4 records of 2 hours (8:30 - 10:30 / 10:30 - 12:30 / 13:00 - 15:00 / 15:00 - 17:00)
Typically, i would like to split this row :

```
From
Title StartTime            StopTime
Task1 2013-11-12 09:00     2013-11-12 14:00
To
Title StartTime            StopTime
Task1 2013-11-12 09:30     2013-11-12 10:30
Task1 2013-11-12 10:30     2013-11-12 12:30
Task1 2013-11-12 12:30     2013-11-12 14:00
```

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Why StartTime in the Output `09:30` not `09:00`?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc33a/17)

```
select [TaskName],
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar,StartTime,108)<pStart
       THEN floor(CAST(StartTime as float))+Cast(pStart as Datetime)
       ELSE StartTime
       END as StartTime,
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar,StopTime,108)>pEnd
       THEN floor(CAST(StopTime as float))+Cast(pEnd as Datetime)
       ELSE StopTime
       END as StopTime

FROM T       

JOIN 
(
  SELECT '08:30:00' as pStart, '10:30:00' as pEnd 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '10:30:00' as pStart, '12:30:00' as pEnd
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '13:00:00' as pStart, '15:00:00' as pEnd  
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '15:00:00' as pStart, '17:00:00' as pEnd  
)  as DayParts 
  ON (CONVERT(varchar,StartTime,108)<=pEnd 
       AND 
      CONVERT(varchar,StopTime,108)>=pEnd
     ) 
     OR 
     (
      CONVERT(varchar,StopTime,108)>=pStart
       AND 
      CONVERT(varchar,StartTime,108)<=pStart   
     )  

ORDER BY TaskName,StartTime
```